# Mongo: running .find()s and .update()s in order

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

I want to:

1. Get some items from collection X;
2. Get other items from X;
3. Update the items from #1 to have the same value as items from #2
4. Update the items from #2 to have the same value as items from #1

Basically a swap.

However when I tried this:

```
var cursorOn = db.car.find({T: 'e46dba7', State: "On"});
var cursorOff = db.car.find({T: 'e46dba7', State: "Off"});

while (cursorOn.hasNext()) {
    doc = cursorOn.next();    
    db.car.update(
        {_id: doc._id},
        {$set:{"State": "Off"}},
        {writeConcern: { wtimeoutMS: 50000 }}
    );
}

while (cursorOff.hasNext()) {
    doc = cursorOff.next();    
    db.car.update(
        {_id: doc._id},
        {$set:{"State": "On"}},
        {writeConcern: { wtimeoutMS: 50000 }}
    );
}
```

All the records were updated to `On` instead of the values from each respective group being "swapped".

I also tried this:

```
let cursorOn = await db.car.find({T: 'e46dba7', State: "On"});
let cursorOff = await db.car.find({T: 'e46dba7', State: "Off"});
```

This results in an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at /root/MongoScripts/update.js
```

How can I make it synchronous so that the result would be as I expect it to be. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you're likely ending up in a situation where your `cursorOn` and `cursorOff` cursors are working against a live resultset, rather than two individual snapshots.

I would expect this is what happens:

1. `cursorOn` is set up to look for { "State": "On" }.
2. `cusorOff` is set up to look for { "State": "Off" }.
3. `cursorOn` runs through all the "On" documents, setting them all to "Off".
4. `cursorOff` runs through all the "Off" documents, but this also includes all of the documents that were set to "Off" in Step #3.

The net result is that all the documents that were either "On" or "Off" at the start would have been switched to "On", as you've observed.

Rather than dealing with a cursor, I think you want to deal with an eagerly-loaded array by calling [`toArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) on the cursor itself. Combining this with a [`projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) would be a good idea, as you only need the IDs of the documents you're working with.

I'm no MongoDB expert - This is just what the problem looks like to me. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly a jQuery deferred expert, but I have used it to make logic synchronous

```
$.when(firstFuntion).then(secondFunction);
​
function firstFunction (cursorOn) {

    var $dfd = $.Deferred()

    while (cursorOn.hasNext()) {
        doc = cursorOn.next();    
        db.car.update(
            {_id: doc._id},
            {$set:{"State": "Off"}},
            {writeConcern: { wtimeoutMS: 50000 }}
        );
    }

    return $dfd.promise()
}

function secondFunction (cursorOff) {

    var $dfd = $.Deferred();

    while (cursorOff.hasNext()) {
        doc = cursorOff.next();    
        db.car.update(
            {_id: doc._id},
            {$set:{"State": "On"}},
            {writeConcern: { wtimeoutMS: 50000 }}
        );
    }

    return $dfd.promise();
};
```

Using a when then allows you to control the order of execution as long as you used a promise - the .when() won't execute until the .then() has had it's promise fulfilled.

I hope this helps dude, or at least spurs on some creative thinking :)

Edit: forgot to include this link to [jQuery deferred.promise()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/); I hope it's helpful.